# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT vs. COALESCE concerning NULL values

Tags: mysql, null

### UPDATE

I just noticed that in the server the column `table3.note` values are `NULL` and on my local machine they are empty strings. After this embarassing discovery I made some testing and everything works the same on both platforms.

And this is what they produce if I have two cells and the second one contains an actual value (the first is `NULL`):

```
//1st
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`table3`.`note`, '') SEPARATOR ';') AS `table3_note`
//var_dump(): array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(4) "Test" } 

//2nd
GROUP_CONCAT(`table3`.`note`) SEPARATOR ';') AS `table3_note`
//var_dump(): array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Test" }
```

So the 1st query (`COALESCE`) retrieves `NULL`s as empty strings and the 2nd strips all `NULL` values from the result set. (This is unacceptable because I have many arrays and they need to be synchronized.)

The original problem is solved because of my mistake. I would still like to know why `GROUP_CONCAT` ignores `NULL`s even if checked.

Here's the query that works properly (doesn't strip the `NULL`s):

```
SELECT `table1`.*
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`table3`.`id`, '') SEPARATOR ';') AS `t3_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`table3`.`note`, '') SEPARATOR ';') AS `t3_note`,
  FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `table3` ON `table3`.`id` = `table1`.`id`
      GROUP BY `table1`.`id`
```

So why this one ignores `NULL`s? (More query option that ignore `NULL` values are on the original question section.)

```
SELECT `table1`.*
  GROUP_CONCAT(`table3`.`id` SEPARATOR ';') AS `t3_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`table3`.`note` SEPARATOR ';') AS `t3_note`,
  FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `table3` ON `table3`.`id` = `table1`.`id`
      GROUP BY `table1`.`id`
```

### Original question (not important, my bad...)

A part of my query that uses three tables (1:n relationship, I'm mapping multiple rows from `table2` and `table3` to a single `table1` row). Two alternatives for fetching a single cell value:

```
 //1st
 GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`table3`.`note`, '') SEPARATOR ';') AS `table3_note`

 //2nd
 GROUP_CONCAT(`table3`.`note`) SEPARATOR ';') AS `table3_note`
```

Both work fine on local machine but only the first one on the server. On my local machine I get a correct amount of empty array values when using the 1st or 2nd option (using `var_dump()`). On the server the 2nd option returns only an empty array if there are no values on any `table3_note` (there are many `table3_id`s and other fields not showed in the query).

**So the question is why?** Both functions claim to return `NULL` if there are no non-null values according the manual.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Is the following information relevevant or am I missing something from the manual?

- Local machine: MySQL Client API version 5.1.44
- Server: MySQL Client API version 5.0.51a

Is the answer so simple that the server handles the `COALESCE` function like my local machine, but the `GROUP_CONCAT` function is handled differently because of the non matching MySQL Client API versions?

I now have a working solution so this isn't a real question in a sense that I need to fix this. I'd just like to know why this is as it is. And are there any pitfalls in using `COALESCE` like I'm using? Is there a danger that arrays are not properly synchronized when printing them using a `for` loop? (At least a quick testing didn't reveal any problems.)

---

Final notes. I tried using these and some other methods (`IFNULL`, `IS NULL` etc.) like suggested for example in these questions:

- [GROUP_CONCAT return NULL if any value is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101191/group-concat-return-null-if-any-value-is-null)
- [Rows with null value for group_concat not returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614316/rows-with-null-value-for-group-concat-not-returned)

But the result was the same: works on a local machine but not on the server. Queries below:

```
//another option for the query
IF(SUM(`table3`.`note` IS NULL) = 0, GROUP_CONCAT(`table3`.`note` SEPARATOR ';'), NULL) AS `table3_note`

//and another one...
ISNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(`table3`.`note` SEPARATOR ';'), '') AS `table3_note`
```

[MySQL manual also says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

> Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.

Does this mean `COALESCE` doesn't ignore `NULL` values like `GROUP_CONCAT` does, even if checked? This still doesn't explain the different behaviours of the server and local machine. Or does it?

Comment: It's impossible to figure out why a summary function like `GROUP_CONCAT` might not work the way you want unless you reveal the `GROUP BY` part of your query.  If you don't have `GROUP BY` in your query, put it there. Or, understand every single word of this web page. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html Seriously.

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer and edit your question.

Comment: Back in the days where SQL was designed, and/or mySQL started development, I guess it made more sense to skip NULLs. If you use SQL to directly output human readable reports, it makes more sense. But nowadays, it is mostly used to feed data to complex programs, and OO code, which demands better predictability and precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the query that works properly (doesn't strip the `NULL`s):

```
SELECT `table1`.*
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`table3`.`id`, '') SEPARATOR ';') AS `t3_id`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(`table3`.`note`, '') SEPARATOR ';') AS `t3_note`,
  FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `table3` ON `table3`.`id` = `table1`.`id`
      GROUP BY `table1`.`id`
```

Original question is left intact. It's quite messy and difficult to understand but the query above works for me.